# How to create KeyVaultClient instance using existing access_token string?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-keyvault

I have implemented Key Vault access token generator using below codebase:

```
private async Task<string> GetStaticToken(string authority, string resource)
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    var credential = new ClientCredential(_appSettings.ClientId, _appSettings.ClientSecret);
    AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credential);
    return result.AccessToken;
}
```

I know how to use this token into Authorization header and get the secret values using Rest API call. But can we use the same AccessToken string into below code base:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));                            
builder.AddAzureKeyVault($"https://{myVaultName}.vault.azure.net/", keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
Configuration = builder.Build();
```

Here is it possible to re-use AccessToken string value, while creating KeyVaultClient? Something like below:

```
var tokenValue = GetStaticToken (authority, resource);
var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(tokenValue);
```

Basically I would like to generate token at once and reuse string everywhere, even outside my application scope.

**Note**: I am aware that token will come with expiration time duration. That time GetToken will be called again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can make a callback that returns that token:

```
var kvClient = new KeyVaultClient((authority, resource, scope) => Task.FromResult(tokenValue));
```

This simply replaces the call to get a token with an already completed Task with the token in it.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea how much lifetime a token has, when does it get expire ?

Comment: By default 1 hour, though that default can be modified.